# google apps script convert string to object

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question about the date convert:
in sheet, I have a date '05/11/2018', I need to get next date 06/11/2018.

```html
var end=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(coach_date.getTime()+1*3600000*24), 'GMT', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
var start = new Date();
var events = calendar.getEvents(start,end);
```

it shows the 'end' is string, not object. it has to be getEvents(object,object)

so I used end = new Date(end); it got '11/06/2018', change month from Nov to June.

How could I fix it, then use it on getevents() feature.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: please mark as answered if that solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`Utilities.formatDate()` converts the date object into a string. So, use

```
var end = coach_date.setDate(coach_date.getDate()+1);
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot call method "setDate" of undefined.(line 114, file "xxxx")

Comment: @J.W. define `coach_date`